# Kafka - Error creating broker listeners between Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, apache-kafka

We are trying to message from Linux to windows using apache Kafka;
Zookeeper and Kafka is configured in both OS and messaging happening in respective localhost;

Error while messaging from windows to Linux;

> error -
> ERROR Error when sending message to topic my_topic with key: null, value: 5 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic my_topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

> [2020-10-09 11:24:22,903] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 51 : {my_topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
> Terminate batch job (Y/N)?

> [20-10-09 11:24:28,979] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-56715] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 81 : {my_topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
> Processed a total of 0 messages

```
Listed below are the configuration files for Linux server endpoint 
    
#producer properties
metadata.broker.list=localhost:9092,192.168.1.3:9092,192.168.0.103:9092 

#consumer properties
zookeeper.connect=127.0.0.1:2181,192.168.1.3:2181,192.168.0.103:2181
#consumer group id
group.id=test-consumer-group


#server properties
broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.3:9092,192.168.0.103:9092
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181


#192.168.0.103 is windows machine
#172.22.3.28 is Linux machine

Windows producer – 
kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list 172.22.3.28:9092 --topic my_topic

Linux Consumer-
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server 192.168.0.103:9092 --topic my_topic --from-beginning
```

we started configuring kafka individual in linux and windows and successfully send message thru localhost.
presume real-time messaging across OS is possible with kafka. please correct.

Comment: How are you connecting from subnet 192.xxx to 172.xxx?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the `advertised.listeners` such that the Windows client can correctly connect to the Linux broker.

If the Linux broker has IP `172.22.3.28` then the config should look like:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://172.22.3.28:9092
```

Ref: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc